# Routing API Views in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

Is there any common pattern for routing `APIViews` (ie, *not* `ViewSets`) with Django Rest Framework?

For example, if I've got an API View that takes an optional argument:

```
class ReportView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, report_name=None):
         # … stuff …
         return Response(report)
```

Is there any standard pattern — apart from writing out a standard Django URL router — for routing that view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any standard pattern — apart from writing out a standard Django URL router — for routing that view?

ViewSets & Routers *are* the pattern if you want standardised routing.

If you're using views then just use a regular Django URLconf.

Comment: How can I add to the browsable API the views that use the regular Django URLconf?

Answer (score 18):

Being able to add simple API views is quite useful for displaying the urls in `root-api` view.

Here is the simplest extension of `DefaultRouter` that enables registering not only viewsets but also simple API views:

```python
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework import routers, viewsets
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

class DefaultRouterWithSimpleViews(routers.DefaultRouter):
    """
    Extends functionality of DefaultRouter adding possibility
    to register simple API views, not just Viewsets.
    """

    def get_routes(self, viewset):
        """
        Checks if the viewset is an instance of ViewSet,
        otherwise assumes it's a simple view and does not run
        original `get_routes` code.
        """
        if issubclass(viewset, viewsets.ViewSetMixin):
            return super(DefaultRouterWithSimpleViews, self).get_routes(viewset)

        return []

    def get_urls(self):
        """
        Append non-viewset views to the urls
        generated by the original `get_urls` method.
        """    
        # URLs for simple views
        ret = []
        for prefix, viewset, basename in self.registry:

            # Skip viewsets
            if issubclass(viewset, viewsets.ViewSetMixin):
                continue

            # URL regex
            regex = '{prefix}{trailing_slash}$'.format(
                prefix=prefix,
                trailing_slash=self.trailing_slash
            )

            # The view name has to have suffix "-list" due to specifics
            # of the DefaultRouter implementation.
            ret.append(url(
                regex, viewset.as_view(),
                name='{0}-list'.format(basename)
            ))

        # Format suffixes
        ret = format_suffix_patterns(ret, allowed=['json', 'html'])

        # Prepend URLs for viewsets and return
        return super(DefaultRouterWithSimpleViews, self).get_urls() + ret
```

Now you can use simple Django views alongside with the rest framework ViewSets:

```python
router = DefaultRouterWithSimpleViews()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, 'users')                # <- Viewset!         
router.register(r'reset-pwd', ResetPasswordView, 'reset_pwd')  # <- Simple view!
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

**Update:** Added support of format suffixes (thanks to [alexander-klimenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319271/alexander-klimenko))

Comment: Just little notice. This router will produce urls without suffix (*.json, *.jsonp) support. You have to call format_suffix_patterns for extra patterns.

Comment: @AlexanderKlimenko thanks! I've updated the answer - please double-check if it's correct.

Comment: Maybe to make this example code easier to understand, you could also include a short example of how it would be used?

Comment: Thank you for the example, but i got this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'register'
`

Comment: @М.Б. it might be a typo in your code. Perhaps you missed the first line where `router` instance is created?

Comment: @DavidAvsajanishvili Nope. I have moved from this issue, by implementing it via filtering queryset. But i got troubles at routes like `profiles/1/albums/1/` still can't implement this.

Comment: @DavidAvsajanishvili i did it finally! I found a way. I will link git repo here when get project done.

Comment: @М.Б. Can you please let me know how you got the `profiles/1/albums/1/` like routes to be registered?

Comment: Hey @PaoloC, I'm sorry for a bit late response. There it is how: https://bitbucket.org/milosb793/gallery-django/src/9b49cdfdcfbbc911cec23ed30ded30f6c4042522/src/albums/api/views.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default Also, check whole repository, it may be helpful.

Comment: @М.Б. Maybe I got the wrong link but in that report I don't see any reference to a usage of a DRF `SimpleRouter`. Wrong repo?

Comment: @PaoloC No, I haven't used SimpleRouter, I've solved it in another way. Check it.