# Nested routes with APIViews in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, api, nested

I'm writing my school project, building Django Rest API. And I have next entities: `Profiles`, `Albums`, `Images`, `Comments`, `Likes`.

What I'm trying is make resources accessible in this way:
`api/v1/profiles/1/albums` --> get all the albums from profile with the id 1

On the examples, there is `ViewSet` used, instead `APIView` which I wanted to use ( I'm really newbie, and I don't even know can I use `ViewSet` for CRUID operations ).
I've tried to implement the following:

- https://blog.apptension.com/2017/09/13/simple-nested-api-using-django-rest-framework/
- [Routing API Views in Django Rest Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818179/routing-api-views-in-django-rest-framework?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#routers

and many others, but I can't get it working...

If there is some detailed tutorial, please reference it, I'd really need to be fast finishing this.

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this solved using the `get_queryset` and `get_object`. There is a full example for other people looking for help:

In **urls.py**:

```
url(r'(?P<profile_id>\d+)/albums/(?P<album_id>\d+)/images/(?P<image_id>\d+)/comments/(?P<comment_id>\d+)/?$',CommentDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='profile-album-image-comment'),
```

In **views.py**:

```
class GetCommentsAPI(ListAPIView):
"""

"""
serializer_class = CommentSerializer
filter_backends = [SearchFilter]  # this must be array!
authentication_classes = [AllowAny]

def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
   # ipdb.set_trace(context=5)
    profile_id = self.kwargs.get("profile_id")
    if not profile_id:
        return Response({"status": "fail"}, status=403)

    profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=profile_id)

    album_id = self.kwargs.get("album_id")
    if not album_id:
        return Response({"status": "fail"}, status=403)
    album = Album.objects.get(pk=album_id, owner_id=profile_id)

    if not album:
        return Response({"status": "fail"}, status=404)

    image_id = self.kwargs.get("image_id")
    if not image_id:
        return Response({"status": "fail"}, status=403)
    image = Image.objects.get(pk=image_id, album_id=album_id)

    queryset_list = Comment.objects.filter(image__pk=image_id)
    return queryset_list

class CommentDetailAPIView(DestroyModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin, RetrieveAPIView):
"""

"""
queryset = Comment.objects.all()
serializer_class = DetailedCommentSerializer
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

def get_object(self):
    profile_id = self.kwargs.get("profile_id")
    profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=profile_id)
    if not profile:
        return JsonResponse({"status":"fail","code":404})

    album_id = self.kwargs.get("album_id")
    album = Album.objects.get(pk=album_id)
    if not album:
        return JsonResponse({"status": "fail", "code": 404})

    image_id = self.kwargs.get("image_id")
    image = Image.objects.get(pk=image_id)
    if not image:
        return JsonResponse({"status": "fail", "code": 404})

    comment_id = self.kwargs.get("comment_id")
    if not comment_id:
        return JsonResponse({"status": "fail", "code": 404})

    comment = get_object_or_404(queryset=Comment.objects.all(), pk=comment_id, image__pk=image_id)
    return comment

def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

When I get the project done, I will link the repo here. Good luck!

---

**Edit**: The repo, a bit old now: https://github.com/milosb793/django-gallery-api

Answer (score 1):

may be you need [extra-link-and-actions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#extra-link-and-actions), for example:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route

class ProfileView
    # Your Code Here

    @detail_route(methods=['GET'])
    def albums(request, pk=None):
        # Heed to change related name 'albums_set'
        qs = self.get_object().albums_set.all()
        serializer = AlbumsSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Aha! You recommend to do this with decorators? I will try when I got home. Thank you for your opinion!